# Why the first code works and the second does not work?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how JavaScript deals with code, what happens in the browser
Code 1 (working code)

```js
let array = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 'Item 2') {
        item = item.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        item = item.toLowerCase();
    }
    console.log(item);
});
```

```
// output item 1
//        ITEM 2
//        item 3
```

Code 2 (not working)

```js
let array = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 'Item 2') {
        item.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        item.toLowerCase();
    }
    console.log(item);
});
```

```
// output Item 1
//        Item 2
//        Item 3
```

Comment: strings are immutable.

Comment: Item.lowercase isn't saved the second time into item.

Comment: second code ise not assign item. it must be like
item = item.toUpperCase();

Comment: @NinaScholz that's just part of it. The point is that `toUpperCase` doesn't modify the string in place, but that would be the case even if strings were mutable.

Comment: Please perform a [minimum investigation](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+toUpperCase+does+not+change+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item.toUpperCase();` returns the uppercased string that is why when you do 
`item = item.toUpperCase();` the uppercased string is assigned to `item` and since `item` is a array element, the element is changed by its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here **item** = `item.toUpperCase();` in bold is creating a local variable which is getting printed , but in the later case it is just the reference and the function argument which is printing

Comment: In both case `item` is local variable but first saved changes and second doesn't